# how to do hyperparameter optimization in large data?

Tags: python, performance, machine-learning, large-data, hyperparameters

I almost finished my time series model, collected enough data and now I am stuck at hyperparameter optimization.

And after lots of googling I found new & good library called ultraopt, but problem is that how much amount of fragment of data should I use from my total data (~150 GB) for hyperparameter tuning. And I want to try lots of algorithm and combinations, is there any faster and easy way?

Or

Is there any math involved, something like,
mydata = 100%size

hyperparameter optimization with 5% of mydatasize,

optimized hyperparameter *or+ or something with left 95% of datasize   #something like this

To get a similar result as full data used for optimization at a time. Is there any shortcut for these?

I am using Python 3.7,
CPU: AMD ryzen5 3400g,
GPU: AMD Vega 11,
RAM: 16 GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyperparameter tuning is typically done on the validation set of a train-val-test split, where each split will have something along the lines of 70%, 10%, and 20% of the entire dataset respectively. As a baseline, random search can be used while [Bayesian optimization with Gaussian processes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.2944) has been shown to be more compute efficient. [scikit-optimize](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/auto_examples/bayesian-optimization.html) is a good package for this.

Comment: thanks it helped me lot, after that i google it find these site it gives good information on [optimization ](https://blog.floydhub.com/guide-to-hyperparameters-search-for-deep-learning-models/)

Answer (score 0):

A good python library for hyper-parameter tuning is [`keras tuner`](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.06560.pdf). You can utilize different tuners in this library, but for the large data, as you've mentioned, [`Hyperband Optimization`](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.06560.pdf) can be state-of-the-art and appropriate one.

Comment: thanks for answering iam using darts library for timeseries prediction i can't use keras tuner but i will implement hyperband optimization technique .

Comment: @UjwalS, Of course, you can, as there are multiple tuners such as scikit learn tuner.